# start ipython notebook with python file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I am not very familiar with python/ipython but somebody was asking me whether it is possible to start an ipython notebook with a specific python file. It then could be used for debugging.
another software then would create a .py-file in the temp folder and would call an ipython notebook with this file.
Is it possible or does it make sense at all?

Comment: I think what you need is to create an `ipython profile`, try `ipython --help-all` to read more what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Since the question is quite broad and asking for recommendations, here are my suggestions:

1. cross-platform nbopen, which opens ipynb using command-line or optional explorer integration:

https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen

Please note that I have one open ticket for complete Windows explorer integration:

https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen/issues/12

[copied from github page]

Installation:

```
pip install nbopen
```

Usage:

```
nbopen AwesomeNotebook.ipynb
```

2. run ipynb without launching the browser interface, with many useful options:

https://github.com/paulgb/runipy

[copied from github page]

Installation:

```
$ pip install runipy
```

To run a  .ipynb  file as a script, run:

```
$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb
```

To save the output of each cell back to the notebook file, run:

```
$ runipy -o MyNotebook.ipynb
```

To save the notebook output as a new notebook, run:

```
$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb OutputNotebook.ipynb
```

To run a  .ipynb  file and generate an  HTML  report, run:

```
$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb --html report.html
```

Comment: `runipy` is unmaintained and deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about launching an iPython notebook server via Python, I use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from IPython.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance
from IPython.lib import passwd
from socket import gethostname
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", module = "zmq.*")
sys.argv.append("notebook")
sys.argv.append("--IPKernelApp.pylab='inline'")
sys.argv.append("--NotebookApp.ip=" + gethostname())
sys.argv.append("--NotebookApp.open_browser=False")
sys.argv.append("--NotebookApp.password=" + passwd())
launch_new_instance()
```

Obviously you can change the arguments if you so desire.

At my work we have one use case that does what you're saying--automatically generates a python file, then loads a new ipython server for the user to access it. However, it's a pretty special use case--for normal debugging, I would recommend just starting in iPython and not making your *.py file until the bugs are gone.

***OR***

If you're talking about actually automatically navigating to the page that corresponds to a python file made available by an ipython notebook server, then (1) make sure you're using ipython 2, and (2) figure out what you're desired url is (it should be deterministic) and (3) use the [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/webbrowser.html) to navigate to that url.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a look and try to understand :-). To explain 'debugging': The application takes configured python-scripts from users which might be buggy. It would be nice if in case of an error the user can launch the ipython notebook with the python script

Comment: That sounds like a pretty cool idea to make debugging a bit more use friendly. I hope it works for you!

Comment: is this documented anywhere? I can't find any official reference on this

Comment: The command line options are documented here: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Comment: @metaperture the first step no longer work, is there any workaround it. I have been debugging it but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess, os

def executeJupyter():
    env_dir = "../main_env_dir/"
    os.chdir(env_dir)

    # source jupyter_env/bin/activate
    env_activate = "jupyter_env/bin/activate_this.py"

    activate_env = exec(open(env_activate).read(), {'__file__': env_activate})

    # Open jupyter notebook as a subprocess
    openJupyter = "jupyter notebook"
    subprocess.Popen(openJupyter, shell=True)

 executeJupyter()
```

Make sure you change the `env_dir` (directory where you have the env of your jupyter notebook) and the `env_activate` to your own.

Answer (score -1):

To start a ipython notebook with a certain notebook directory, use the `--notebook-dir` command line option:

```
ipython notebook --notebook-dir=/Users/harold/temp/
```