# Start IPython notebook from REPL

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

it's possible to start `ipython console` from python REPL like this

```
from IPython import embed; embed()
```

I was wondering if there is something similar for `ipython notebook`.

Comment: could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338688/start-ipython-notebook-with-python-file

Comment: You can launch the notebook web application, but it runs kernels in subprocesses, so you don't see your namespace in a notebook. There's not currently a way to attach a notebook to an already running Python process.